# 20 programmers have to test 5 programs. In how many ways can you divide programmers?

Tags: combinatorics

20 programmers have to test 5 programs. 1st program must be tested by exactly 4 people, 2nd program - by exactly 7 people. Remaining programmers can choose whichever program they want to test. In how many ways can you divide programmers?

My attempt:

I must choose 4 people from the 20 programmers which I can do in ${20! \over 4!16!}$ ways. Then I have to choose 7 programmers from the remaining ${20-4=16}$ programmers which I can do in ${16! \over 7!9!}$. The rest of the ${16-7 = 9}$ programmers can choose whichever program they want..

And this is where I got stuck. Can I look at it as combinations with repetition? Each of $9$ programmer can choose one of three numbers $3$, $4$ or $5$ which can happen in $C_{11}^{9}$ ways.

So together it would look like

$${20!16!11! \over 4!16!7!9!9!2!} = {20!11!\over4!7!9!9!2!}$$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: 1st program must be tested by exactly 4 or at least 4?

Comment: 3rd, 4th, 5th must be tested by at least 1 or no?

Comment: The questions says that they "have to test 5 programs". That seems to exclude the possibility of a program being tested by $0$ programmers.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel "Exactly". I will edit it in the post.

Comment: @Coolwater There could be a program without testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in counting the number of ways to assign programmers to the first two programs is great.

You want the remaining three programs to be tested by $9$ programmers, and it doesn't matter how many test each one. One way to count the ways to do that is by inclusion/exclusion. Where each programmer chooses one of three, and then we subtract out the cases where not all three programs get tested:

$$3^9-\binom32 2^9 +\binom31 1^9$$

If we are allowing the possibility that a program can go without testing, then you can just use $$3^9.$$

Comment: Wouldn't the solution with $3^9$ include order in which the programmers chose the program to test?

Comment: It's like counting $9$-letter words in a three letter alphabet. The word $AAABBBCCA$ is the same no matter whether we write the letters from left to right, from right to left, or in some other order. All that we're counting is which program each programmer ends up on, not the order in which they made those choices. To count that, we'd need another factor of $9!$.

Comment: To make it clearer, try thinking it through with something like 4 programmers and 2 programs, where you can see all of the options.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs It just doesn't seem right.. If i have 4 balls and I have to put them in 2 boxes, can I do it in $2^4$ ways?

Comment: Yes! Try it. Assuming the balls are distinguishable, that's exactly correct. Write it down to convince yourself; $2^4$ is only $16$

Comment: If the balls are indistinguishable, and all you care about is how many end up in each box, then there are only $5$ ways, but if that's how you're interpreting this question, then all of your work at the beginning doesn't make sense. You're treating programmers as distinguishable from the start.

Comment: But the balls are all the same. I counted 5 ways.

Comment: Are the programmers all the same?

Comment: If programmers are like balls that are all the same, then the whole calculation of $\frac{20!}{4!16!}$ is senseless. Just put four balls in that box, and move on, if we don't care *which* balls they are, there's only one way to do that.

Comment: Ok, I guess they are not the same. I think I got it now. Thanks a lot, mate! :)